# Visual Studio, link projects together and test

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, libraries

I'm seriously losing my mind. I've been developing in Linux for the past five years, so I'm kinda new to the visual studio / microsoft world.

Here is the problem: I have

- a project consisting of four classes, linked to the ITK library, to implements some functionalities such as IO, data transform and so on. This will compile in a static library or .lib (let's call it **Algorithm**);
- a project that defines public high-level function calls, which is based on the static library above (let's call it **AlgorithmFacade**)
- a UnitTest project to test the classes of Alogirthm (let's call it **AlgorithmTest**)

Now, this is what I do

- I create a solution to contain them all
- I link the ITK libraries in Algorithm (i.e. fill up the fields: Include, Additional Dependencies and Additional Library Dependency)
- #include the classes header I want to use in the AlgorithmFacade project
- link the ITK libraries in AlgorithmFacade in the same manner as I did for Algorithm, otherwise it complains that it cannot find "itkImage" and stuff like that
- Do the exact same thing for the AlorithmTest
- Run the test
- Get 970 warnings of all possibile kinds
- Follow the urban legend that warnings can be ignored
- Get an error like "I dont find the code for Algorithm.lib"
- Despair.

I kinda have the feeling that I'm over'engineering it. But if I try to write unit tests, facade and implementation all in one project VS complains.

- Is there a better solution?
- do I have to include every time all the libraries from scratch?
- Cant I just do a project that includes these libraries and unit tests and subprojects that *automatically* inherit those libraries?

PS I'm using native C++ and not the CLR.

PPS I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the few errors you gave us, it sounds like AlgorithmFacade needs to have Algorithm.lib in its linker->Input section.  AlgorithmTest needs to have Algorithm.lib in its linker->Input section as well, and possibly AlgorithmFacade.lib.  I'm still not sure what projects use what.

What else you may be running in to is a build order issue.  If you right click on your solution name in the solution explorer and drop down to properties, you'll see a project dependency section.  AlgorithmFacade depends on Algorithm.  AlgorithmTest also depends on Algorithm.

Also, make sure any changes you make are applied to both the release and debug versions of your build, or any other builds you may have.  This can be the cause of massive headaches.

Comment: I add them as reference: right click on the project > Reference... > ADD > project. Shouldn't this be enough?

Comment: It should.  But it will not set the building order.

Comment: Now that I've had a chance to look at my vs solution, I don't see Reference in the right click menu.  You can easily check the project dependencies by going to the Common Properties section of the solution, right click solution->Properties.  Here you can set what projects depend on what, this is totally separate from designating what projects link to what libraries.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant: even by setting the project dependencies they dont see each other classes nor libraries. It's like this "dependency" option is just for decoration.

Comment: I'm not sure what the References thing does, I've never used or seen that before.

Comment: I used for to include .dll

Comment: Gotcha.  Any sort of include of header files/libraries does not set the build order.  Has to be done the way I described.